# How to reset field when submit success

Tags: angular

My problem is that after successfully saving the data, one field in the form is not cleared. I call this field from another component

I reset the form with `this.addDiagnosisForm.reset();` and tried to clear the problem field with `(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('diagnosisField')).remove;`. But it is not that, because the field is not cleared completely

```
    <div class="form-row">

            <label for="problemField" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">problemField<span class="required-span">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 d-flex">
                <app-dictionary-entry-search name="problemField" [dictCode]="'problemField'" class="w-100 mr-1"
                (onSetDictionaryEntry)="setDictionaryEntry($event)"  required></app-dictionary-entry-search>
            </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-row">
            <label for="successField"  class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">successField<span class="required-span">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select class="form-control custom-select  validation-field" name="successField"  [(ngModel)]="successField" required>
                <option *ngFor="let item of successField" [ngValue]="item.code">{{successField}}</option>
              </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
<input class="form-control" id="diagnosisField" 
       [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed" [disabled]="disabled"
       (selectItem)="getItemValue($event)" [ngbTypeahead]="search"
       [editable]="false" [resultTemplate]="rt"
       [inputFormatter]="formatter"
       [placeholder]="disabled ? '' : 'testMessage'"
       [(ngModel)]="value"/>
```

Comment: Where is the control who's Id = `diagnosisField`?

Comment: `  <input class="form-control" id="diagnosisField" [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed" [disabled]="disabled"
               (selectItem)="getItemValue($event)" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [editable]="false"
               [resultTemplate]="rt" [inputFormatter]="formatter"
               [placeholder]="disabled ? '' : 'testMessage'" [(ngModel)]="value"/>  `

Answer (score -1):

This **answer** is based on **AngularJS** but I think it might help you.

First of all try to assign your ngModel like this : 
Declaring a common scope variable to your form :

```
$scope.formName = {};
```

Then assign ngModel to fileds like this :
username :

```
$scope.formName.username
```

password :

```
$scope.formName.password
```

Keep going in this way.
So when you need to clear all the form elements put this code again :

```
$scope.formName = {};
```

This will reassign / empty the variable.
If you have any doubt comment or if it resoved your problem **Select this as your answer and up vote.**